# Value or label inside a exposed search form and change input form

Tags: views

I've created a three exposed filters:

- Search
- Choose location
- Choose category

Instead of using a label "Search", in input field I want to have a "enter keywords to search" and when the user clicks on that input the letters will disappear. I've seen this in many websites.

Choose location has a label "Choose location" and in drop down menu the first option is "All". Instead of using label, I want the first option (All) to be "Choose location".

Choose category to be exactly like the location desired method.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: What version of drupal are you using

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I've edited my first post.

Comment: How did you get search into the input field in first place. As this is not a view functionality?

Comment: The search input is part of view and it's in filter criteria/ Search:Search Terms. With that search field the user is able to search by words. It's only another filter, not a real search in the whole website.

Comment: That's not what I asked you. You said instead of using label search in input field, you want enter keywords to search. The label is not in the input field. It is on top of the input field

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't want to use label, I want to be able to put a default text "enter keywords to search" with low opacity effect into the input and when the user clicks on that input it immediately disappear the text and the input becomes clear. I'll search for a website that has filter forms as an example.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10146/discussion-between-user2519032-and-4life)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For adding text to your input field, can be done in one of two ways

```
    function myhook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
        if($form_id == "views_exposed_form"){
         dsm($form); // print $form array on the top of the page
          if (isset($form['title'])) {
            $form['title']['#attributes'] = array('placeholder' => array(t('Enter Keywords to search...')));
    }
  }
}
```

Or use [Compact form](https://drupal.org/project/compact_forms)

> Compact Forms presents text fields for selected forms in a more
>   compact fashion using jQuery.
>
> The form item/element fields are overlaid with their respective
>   labels. When the user focuses a field the label fades away nicely, and
>   if the field is left empty the label fades back in again.

**For changing the All to choose location**

```
function your_module_name_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      if($form_state['view']->name == 'your_view_name') {
        $form['your_dropdown_name']['#options']['All'] = t('- Choose Location -'); 
      }
}
```

Comment: I've created a new custom module and tried the code, but I have some undefined error. If the form id is #views-exposed-form-adding-front-page-page-1 #edit-keys, what should I edit in your code example?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Can you please check the chat? If posted there info about the new error.

Comment: That's because you do not have the devel module. I put the dsm function there to enable you get the name of your own field. Yours might not be title. Comment it out to remove the errors